# Sorting Results of a Multi-valued Faceted Search

Tags: lucene, faceted-search

Using bobo-browse [MultiValueFacetHandler](http://code.google.com/p/bobo-browse/source/browse/branches/BR_LUCENE_MIG_2/bobo-browse/src/com/browseengine/bobo/facets/impl/MultiValueFacetHandler.java) to gather multi-valued faceted results, how do I sort these facets by the top-scoring document in each facet?
For example, if:

- Document d1 has facets f1 and f2 and score 3.5
- Document d2 has facets f2 and f3 and score 4.7
- Document d3 has facets f1 and f3 and score 0.9
- Document d4 has facets f2 and f3 and score 2.2
- Document d5 has facet f1 and score 3.4
- Document d6 has facet f3 and score 5.4

I would expect these results in this order:

- f3, f2, f1

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward answer to this question.  Documents don't have enough information to associate different fields, so only easy solution is to generate derived fields whose value is a concatenation of other field values and use this to build facets.